# CSS Layout Issues (Footer & UL Styling)

Tags: css, layout, footer, html-lists

So I'm trying to code out my design for my new portfolio website, but I'm having a few issues there that research and hours of smashing my face against the computer screen have not yet solved. There are two big issues right now that I'm stuck on, though there is yet another that I'm currently considering if I even want to deal with at all.

The first issue is the menu. I want the typeface to go from regular to bold when you hover over it, or when you're on that page. Which works. Problem is when you hover over it, the other two items in the menu adjust slightly because the change in type weight pushes them out. My attempts thus far have all ended with failure.

The second issue is the footer. I want it to stay on the bottom of the page. My research has gotten me this far, but instead of what I wanted, now it actually stays at the bottom of the browser, not at the bottom of the content. Thank you for any help you can give!

The page in question can be found at: http://personal.justgooddesign.net/draft/

Comment: Concerning the footer: are you after a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your footer is getting jumbled up because you float left and clear right.  My personal preference for footers always [starts with this very clean method](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) and builds from there.  If you're getting confused, separate your inner content from the rest of the page and test away.

With fonts, you have to think more like a UI developer than a graphic designer.  Unlike Indesign, Illustrator, etc, fonts and spacing aren't 100% pixel perfect.  What will render one way in one browser will render a very different way in another.  Bolding a font on the web will make it larger, and it will push spacing.  To compensate for that, setup your menu elements to be a bit wider to compensate, then test like crazy.  If you solely rely on margins and padding, then a bolded hover element is going to push the menu around every time.

Just a suggestion, setup your css in a separate file and load it in.  The code will be cached, which will result in a performance improvement on subsequent loads.  Further, you could save yourself a lot of code by doing one class to attach styling to your elements and being mindful positioning relative to other elements.  There's no need to individually style every element in your portfolio for positioning.

Comment: Where do I float left and clear right in the footer? I do that in the li element for the footer items to keep them all in a line, but that isn't causing the footer to screw up like it is, is it? As for the menu elements up top, I've tried setting them up to be a little wider, but every method I've tried has failed. Sorry if I'm not getting it here, my abilities in programming are not quite up to snuff. I try! I just fail a lot :(

Comment: @justin, if you float things left, then you have to clear left.  When in doubt, just try clear:both first.  Floats almost always cause these type of alignment issues.  Secondly, to make that layout easy, think about it as a container with elements in it..float all the elements left.  The first one will start in upper left, second positioned to the right of the first element.  It will run out of space in the parent, and move down to next line, then repeat.  If you're mindful of padding, margins, etc, you just saved 200+ lines of code from your page.  Don't forget to clear at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to fix your footer issue?

```
<p style = "clear:both">
<div id="footer">
```

Also

```
#right {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    height: 600px; //Remove this line
    width: 490px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though! My knowledge of CSS is...workable, but not advanced. I need to study up on it more.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the jump in the menu by setting a fixed width on the `#menu li`, so

```
#menu li {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 40px;   //something like this.
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To fix the footer issue

1. remove `height: 600px;` from the `#right` rule
2. add a clearing `br` in between the `#container div` and the `#footer div`

   ```
   </div>
   <br style="clear:both;">
   <div id="footer">
   ```

Comment: Thanks! That helped. It pushed the menu past the border of the container, I don't know why, but I just messed with the width enough so that it lines up again. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Man I must be something awful at coding CSS because I just took all your extremely helpful suggestions and fixed/ruined the footer! This layout seems to have so many inherent problems with CSS as it is, I'm so very lost here. I wanna thank you all for your help, it's appreciated so very much! There are just so many technical errors here I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You have floating problems as you are not clearing your floats.

- Your div#wrapper is always going to be equal to the height of the viewport.
- Your div#container is collapsed beacuse you have floated div#left to "left", div#right to "right" and also have absolutely positioned div#footer. What this does is that, it takes these divs from the normal flow of the document and subsequently the div#contaiver is not "wrapped" around these three divs (div#left, div#right and div#fotter")
- The same is the case with div#right. The div#intro and div#portfolio have been floated inside the div#right and it is not wrapping it's child divs.

Ther are many ways around these problems. I suggest this.
Include the following code after the last floated element.

```
<div class="float_clear"></div>

div.float_clear
{
clear: both;
}
```

For the menu, there is not enough space, Just add.

```
div#menu>ul>li
{
width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add overflow:hidden to the container...

Whenever you have stuff that is floating, put a div around the floating content and give it

overflow:hidden;
display:block;
width: (some width);

That will fix most floating issues